# how to create a new/assign a new value to a nested variable in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

Robotframework supports 'nested variables' as described [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0.4/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables-inside-variables).

I've tried multiple ways, but I didn't find a way to assign a new value to a nested variable. Check out the example, it doesn't even validate in in RED Editor, on execution the following error message is displayed:

> No keyword with name '${VAR_${nested}_VALUE}=' found.

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR_A_VALUE}=  aValue

*** Test Cases ***
I Got Stuck Here
    Should Be Equal  aValue  ${VAR_A_VALUE}
    ${nested}=  Set Variable    A
    Should Be Equal  aValue  ${VAR_${nested}_VALUE}
    # --- how to assign 
    ${VAR_${nested}_VALUE}=  Set Variable  A new Value  
    # --- or create new variable via nested feeature ?
    ${A_NEW_VAR_${nested}}=  Set Variable  CreatedViaNested
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the keywords [Set test variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable), [Set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable), and [Set global variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) to do what you want.

Here's an example using [Set test variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable):

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR_A_VALUE}=  aValue

*** Test Cases ***
I Got Stuck Here
    Should Be Equal  aValue  ${VAR_A_VALUE}
    ${nested}=  Set Variable    A
    Should Be Equal  aValue  ${VAR_${nested}_VALUE}

    set test variable  ${VAR_${nested}_VALUE}  A new Value    

    should be equal  ${VAR_A_VALUE}  A new Value
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables inside variables work when you use them as arguments to
keywords but they don't work when assigning new variables.
This error comes because `"${A_NEW_VAR_${nested}}"` is not a valid
variable in an assignment and the framework thus thinks it must be a
keyword to execute.

Please find reference from here : [variable inside variable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/zCRGr5090ok)

Comment: accepted, although it isn't a solution, but the confirmation that this isn't possible.
would be great if the offical documentation I linked had the same information as your link

Comment: @Disc-Addict I'm playing an advocate without being called for, but think the other answer should be accepted now - it is correct, and does provide a solution.

Comment: sometimes the solution is easier than we think. didn't get the difference between `Set Variable` and the `Set <Scope> Variable`.
Correct answer is now accepted.